# T-SQL stored procedure output parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exec, sp-executesql

I have a stored procedure called `R_Proc` with a parameter called `id`. Inside I am creating temp table `##Insert_Data` for inserting data:

```
set @Sql_Create_Table = 'CREATE TABLE ##Insert_Data...'
exec sp_executesql @Sql_Create_Table
```

Then I have created a cursor for selecting data based on the `id`:

```
declare cur cursor for
    select name from test where id = @id

open cur

fetch next from cur into @name

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @Sql_Search_Table = 'select id from ##Insert_Data where ....'
    exec sp_executesql @Sql_Search_Table

    --I want to get **id from above exec** and pass to another statement below
    set @Sql_Table = 'insert into ##Insert_Data
                          select name from tbl where id=<id from above>'
end
```

Last attempt was :

```
set @Sql_Search_Table ='select '+@id+'=id from ##Insert_Data where ....'
exec sp_executesql @Sql_Search_Table
set @temp = @id

--I want to get **id from above exec** and pass to another statement below
set @Sql_Table = 'insert into ##Insert_Data
                      select name from tbl where id='+@temp+'
```

When I print `@temp` variable the value is null.

I am stuck. How can I do something like this?

Comment: This feels like multiple [XY Problems](http://xyproblem.info). Why are you using a dynamic statement? Whybie that dynamic statement written with a huge security vulnerability in it? Why are you using a (global) temporary table to perform an `INSERT`? Why are you using a `WHILE` when SQL is a set based language and performs awfully at iteration. Take a step back and tell us what you are *really* trying to do as it appears you've gone done multiple wrong rabbits holes here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can see now clearly that i am doing it wrong.
I just figured it out that i have done it very complex.
I was start written the stored procedure last night till morning.
I am rewriting the whole proccess.

Comment: Is this whole thing not just `select name into ##Insert_Data from tbl` or something like that? What are you *actually* trying to do?